# Virtual Host from Apache is different domain/directory but only use first

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I've configured two virtual host `cuckoo.net` and `fb.core.net` are located to local ip address (127.0.0.1)

But when I access the second domain: `fb.core.net`, it always returns the first.

Please consider the below configuration to help me, I really don't know what I am wrong here.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/_iLearning/iCuckoo"
    ServerName cuckoo.net
    ServerAlias www.cuckoo.net
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory d:/_iLearning/iCuckoo>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/_Devs/fbcore/public"
    ServerName fb.core.net
    ServerAlias www.fb.core.net
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory d:/_Devs/fbcore/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add fb.core.net to the `ServerAlias`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/_Devs/fbcore/public"
    ServerName fb.core.net
    ServerAlias www.fb.core.net fb.core.net # you can add more than one here
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory d:/_Devs/fbcore/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

i face this issue today
please check this url
http://alexking.org/blog/2007/11/01/apache-2-only-serves-first-virtual-host

my config i add

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

i think you need to add

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

or change 
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
to 
`<VirtualHost *>`

### My config

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /home/host1/www
    ServerName host1.bdwey.com
    ServerAlias www.host1.bdwey.com
    <Directory "/home/host1/www">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /home/host2/www
    ServerName host2.bdwey.com
    ServerAlias www.host2.bdwey.com
    <Directory "/home/host2/www">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```